# Python "ImportError: No module named twint" on Atom trying to use twint (Python Module)

Tags: python, atom-editor, twint

I'm currently playing around with Python and the Twint module. The problem is that when I try to run the program in Atom, I permanently get this error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hY5k.png)

("ImportError: No module named twint")

The funny thing is that the error message does not appear when I start Atom and run the program for the first time, but from the second time on it does appear. The first time everything works as intended.

What can I do to prevent this?
I have twint obiously installed on my PC.

Edit:
I am able to find the twint package under .atom/packeges and Atom also shows it to me as an installed package, but I still get the error..

Comment: Have you run in the terminal pip install twint or however you installed it on your machine. This can be done in the atom terminal

Comment: When I go to "Packages" in Atom, it even tells me that I have Twint installed, but Atom still can't find it.

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: Hi Joe, no I don't have two different versions installed

Comment: perhaps change your directory to where the package is and see if that helps

Comment: I think I've already done that. What exactly do you mean though?