# Problem Importing Python Twint Module to Jupyter Notebook - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twint'

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, twint

When I try to import the `twint` package (https://pypi.org/project/twint/) to Jupyter Notebook, I get an error message.

```
import twint

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5772b804c290> in <module>
----> 1 import twint

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twint'
```

But I know `twint` is installed allright.

```
C:\Users\my_user>pip show twint

Name: twint
Version: 2.1.20
Summary: An advanced Twitter scraping & OSINT tool.
Home-page: https://github.com/twintproject/twint
Author: Cody Zacharias
Author-email: codyzacharias@pm.me
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\my_user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: beautifulsoup4, pysocks, aiohttp, cchardet, googletransx, schedule, geopy, fake- 
useragent, aiohttp-socks, elasticsearch, pandas, aiodns
Required-by:
```

I've looked at [Python "ImportError: No module named twint" on Atom trying to use twint (Python Module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911295/python-importerror-no-module-named-twint-on-atom-trying-to-use-twint-python), and I know I don't have two versions of python installed.

How do I move forward? I'd like to use this or a similar module, and not the Twitter API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to start using twint this morning.
It seems that twint **is only compatible with python 3.6**, whereas I was using a more recent version. I downloaded python 3.6, and ran

```
python3.6 -m pip install twint
```

in the command line. Seems to work now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I created a virtual environment with python 3.6 and twint works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
type this before importing twint